# Do you know why pip list shows one installed version but then python shell shows another?

Tags: python, django, pip, virtualenv, conda

I have created a virtual environment. I activate it with `conda activate my_venv`.
I do `pip list` and check statsmodels version. result -->0.12.1
I do `pip freeze`. The same result.
I get inside of the python shell and execute the next code:

```
import sys
import statsmodels
print(sys.prefix)
print(statsmodels.__version__)
```

the output:

```
'/home/skootik/anaconda3/envs/my_venv'
'0.10.2'
```

Does anybody know why?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Should you use _pip_ in a _conda_ environment? I am not clear on the side effects, maybe it's harmless, I do not know. -- I would suggest you to find out where the `site-packages` directory is for that environment and look inside it if maybe multiple versions of `statsmodels` are installed. If yes, then uninstall `statsmodels` (it might be necessary to call the `uninstall` command multiple times) or recreate the environment from scratch).

Answer (score 1):

1. Check what pip you are using

```
which pip
```

Is it inside `/anaconda3/bin`?

2. Check anaconda envs

```
conda info --envs
```

Is `my_env` == `prodenv`?

3. Try to check version via conda command

```
conda list statsmodels
```

conda has own [package manager](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/understand-conda-and-pip-9e5c67da47cc)